# Invalid customer.address object error when trying to create new Stripe customers in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, stripe-payments, urlfetch

I'm trying to automate the creation and updating of customers on my stripe account with a Google Script, but when passing the customer object, even though it seems to align with the [structure laid out in the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-address) I receive a 400 error response from the Stripe API stating the `address` object is invalid.

**Current Function:** (for POSTing the customer object to the Stripe API)

```
function SendCustomer(details) {
    // determine endpoint based on if sheet row has stripe_customer_id value
    var endpoint;
    if (details.stripe_customer_id && details.stripe_customer_id.length() > 0) {
      // We're updating an existing customer
      endpoint = CUSTOMERS_ENDPOINT + '/' + details.stripe_customer_id;
    } else {
      // We're creating a new customer
      endpoint = CUSTOMERS_ENDPOINT;
    }

    var cust = {
        'address': JSON.stringify({
            'line1': details.street,
            'line2': '',
            'city': details.city,
            'state': details.state,
            // Google Sheets holds a Number, so convert to String as required by Stripe API
            'postal_code': details.postal_code ? details.postal_code.toString() : details.postal_code,
            'country': 'US'
        }),
        'email': details.email,
        'phone': details.phone_cell,
        'name': details.fname + ' ' + details.lname
    }
    Logger.log(cust);
    var options = {
        'method' : 'post',
        'headers': {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + API_KEY
        },
        'payload' : cust
    };
    var cust_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, options)
    var json_response = JSON.parse(cust_response.getContentText());
    return json_response.id
}
```

**Error Message when running the above function:**

```
"error": {
    "message": "Invalid object",
    "param": "address",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? From what I can tell, I'm following the defined structure of the `customer.address` object per the API docs. Could it be the way that `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` is sending the payload that's messing it up? If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: If you look at the request in the Stripe Dashboard, what does the body of the posted data look like?

Comment: For example, in your script, when `address` has only `line1` property, what result will you get?

Comment: @Tanaike I originally only had line1 (my use cases didn't require line2 or country), but I added the other values just to see if maybe that was preventing the object from being seen as valid. Didn't make a difference.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When `address` has only `line1` property, the same error of `"message": "Invalid object","param": "address",` occurs. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike correct, same error.

Comment: Thank you for replying. At stripe-payments, it seems that the data is sent as the form data. But for example, in your case, when the data is sent as JSON, what result will you get?

Comment: @Tanaike I've tried various ways to send the `cust` object you see in the code. UrlFetchApp, from what I've read in it's documentation, naturally sends the `payload` as form data. But, I've also tried using `JSON.stringify(cust)` and setting the `content-type` parameter explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. As other pattern, for example, when `cust` is modified to `var cust={'address':JSON.stringify({'line1':details.street,'line2':'','city':details.city,'state':details.state,'postal_code':details.postal_code?details.postal_code.toString():details.postal_code,'country':'US'}),'email':details.email,'phone':details.phone_cell,'name':details.fname+''+details.lname}`, what result will you get?

Comment: @Tanaike thought of that as well, but same result.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my proposals were not useful. This is due to my poor skill.

Comment: @Tanaike no need to apologise. Thanks for trying to help 

Comment: @taintedzodiac was just able to check this. The dashboard shows the payload as ```{

"address": "{"line1":"123 Test St.","line2":"","city":"Pittsburgh","state":"PA","postal_code":"15237","country":"US"}",

"phone": "412-555-1313",

"name": "John Doe",

"email": null

}```, so it appears UrlFetchApp is turning the customer object into a string. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Hi ! Have you tried using [JSON.stringify](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#work_with_json) as shown in the documentation before sending the request to the API ? You would just need to use ```var payload = JSON.stringify(curl);``` right before using it in the ```options``` object of your request. Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: @MateoRandwolf I have tried that and it didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying many different methods, I finally figured out how to properly construct any nested object (such as the `address` object in this case) to be sent correctly to the Stripe API through Google Apps Scripts. Catching this line in the [UrlFetchApp documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#advanced-parameters), gave me the idea on how to handle the construction of the `customer.address` object so that it's parsed correctly on Stripe's end.

> payload - Description: "...**A JavaScript object is interpreted as a
>   map of form field names to values, where the values can be either
>   strings or blobs.**"

This reminded me of how I saw other form data posted through various services when viewing them in the Chrome Developer Console. So, using that clue I was able to construct the proper structure as such:

```
var cust = {
      'address[line1]': details.street,
      'address[line2]': '',
      'address[city]': details.city,
      'address[state]': details.state,
      'address[postal_code]': details.postal_code ? details.postal_code.toString() : details.postal_code,
      'address[country]': 'US',
      'email': details.email,
      'phone': details.phone_cell,
      'name': details.fname + ' ' + details.lname
    }
    Logger.log(cust);
    var options = {
        'method' : 'POST',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'headers': {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + API_KEY,
        },
        'payload' : cust
    };
    var cust_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, options)
    var json_response = JSON.parse(cust_response.getContentText());
```